# User Registration by Email in SecureSocial, How to?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, securesocial

A bit or problem here, well I figured out how to store users signing up from FB/Twitter using SecureSocial, but how am I to register users using `email-registration`, Can anyone provide me with a brief explanation of how one does it in SecureSocial. I have googled a lot to find tutorials about how thats done, but with no avail.

Yes, of course I can store the token data easily, but in case of email users how am I to integrate the stored data with the user trying to login through the email-password menu. I am **confused** with the whole `work-flow` of `registering user-by-email`

Since I am new to scala, and even new to SecureSocial, I couldn't get the user-regsitration working properly, and didn't properly understand the guide provided in the SecureSocial site regarding this matter.

It would be helpful, if you could provide me with any pointers, or point me to `resources/tutorials`covering the part.

Comment: hhhhm , but I could help if you use play-authenticate instead of secure social.

Comment: Umm, sorry, But I need to work with SecureSocial, its one of the requirements and I am `required` to use it.

Comment: Did you see the sample apps? They show the complete flow.

Comment: By samples you mean -> https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/2.1.3/samples/scala/demo/ , yes I have looked through it. So, similarly like in case of `social-based-logins`, I am supposed to use `token->uuid` ?? as the `Identity.IdentityId.UserID` in case of social logins. It's all new to me being new to play, scala and ...

Comment: Or, can I get a simple brief description of how to work around tokens and their usages.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I researched about my own question and gained some ideas about Token,

As the name itself describes, Tokens are like real world tokens/tickets:

- Tokens-id in SecureSocial exactly are [JAVA UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) generated keys, which are unique and used to describe if a particular SecureSocial request is valid or not.

For example if you have used SecureSocial, you might have come accross links like:

`http://someapp.com/signup/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx`

Most imp part of the Token Object, token-id=> `xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx`, its unique and you will find them in every links connected to email registration and its other functionalities, like :

- Password Change Links
- SignUp Links

I 'll try and posting more elaborate answers, after I learn more about SecureSocial.